# How to select the appropriate baseline calculation for population health studies

Tags: epidemiology

I'm taking over a project where I will need to create baseline measures for public health outcomes (reported annually), for example hospitalisation rates for different demographic groups.

The person who previously worked on this calculated the baselines for each outcome differently. For years T1 to T5 (most recent), at various points they have used:

- Simple Moving Average (SMA: mean of T1:T5 values)
- Weighted Moving Average (WMA: (T5*5 + T4*4 + T3*3 + T2*2 + T1)/15)
- Mean of T5 and WMA

From the documentation given to me, the reasoning for this is as follows (example data below):

- Outcome A shows a gradual decrease in time, so we should weight recent data more heavily and use the WMA value (22.5).
- Outcome B has stayed constant over time, so we should use the SMA value (22.5)
- Outcome C has been mostly stable until a big drop in T5, so we should take the mean of T5 and WMA to weight T5 more heavily (11.3).

My initial feeling is that the same calculation should be used for all outcomes, but I can also see his reasoning. Does anyone have any ideas or resources on how to best choose an appropriate baseline for this sort of data?

```
    T1      T2      T3      T4      T5      SMA     WMA     Mean of T5 and WMA
A   28.7    26.2    23.5    21.7    19.9    24.0    22.5    21.2
B   23.7    22.4    23.3    21.1    22.2    22.5    22.3    22.2
C   12.2    13.7    12.0    13.0    10.5    12.3    12.0    11.3
```

EDIT: The aim of the project is not to compare the rates of outcomes, but to track them over time. Each outcome will have a different target. For example, we may want to see outcome A reduced by 10% over 5 years, outcome B to increase by 20% over 10 years, and C to reduce to 0 within 10 years. We'd be wanting to be able to annually track whether we were on target.

It's an open question of how we want to deal with existing trends (i.e. do we add our targets to be in addition to existing trends), so any feedback on that would be helpful too.

Comment: If you are comparing the outcomes, you should be using the same methods. But, when you say 'baseline', presumably you mean that you will compare these to some rates in future years after one or more intervention, rather than comparing between the outcomes. In that case, the bigger issue is how you will do the comparison when there are obvious time trends in your data. You will probably want to use a method that takes this into account, rather than averaging the baseline measures. If you can give more detail on the comparison(s) you want to make, we can suggest appropriate methods.

Comment: Thanks Azula, I've updated the post with extra information. I hope it's a bit more clear now.
The aim of the project is not to compare the rates of outcomes, but to track them over time. Each outcome will have a different target. For example, we may want to see outcome A reduced by 10% over 5 years, outcome B to increase by 20% over 10 years, and C to reduce to 0 within 10 years. We'd be wanting to be able to annually track whether we were on target.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why the averages are needed at all. If the goal is to reach a target, I would suggest that you look annually at distance from the target or the difference from baseline. But, perhaps the targets are defined on a multi-year basis or the underlying process takes a while to change? In which case, I think that a weighted average might be preferable since it will be more responsive to any programmatic changes you have implemented in the past year. The mean of T5 and WTA is just a weighted average where T5 has a weight of 6 instead of 5, which seems unnecessary.

Comment: Hi Azula, thanks for the feedback. The underlying process will probably take at least a decade to change, which I assume is part of the reason why my predecessor thought to use averages. I'll proceed with weighted averages - it seems to be the the most commonly used approach in any case.